# Jquery regular expression for finding and formatting text parts

Tags: jquery, regex, string, text, find

I used Jquery to have many dynamically generated feedback lines to quiz questions coming from an xml. Sample:

You answered *(Yes.)* Your patient is **at moderate to high risk.**
You answered *(No.)* Your patient is **at low to high risk.**
You answered *(Weekly Dose.)* Your patient is **at moderate risk.**
etc.

How can I find and format different parts of the feedback text? I need to format part of the text with the quotation marks in italic. Also format part of text at the end in bold starting with the word "at" till the period mark?

I guess it would be possible with regular expressions but I haven't used them.
 so far I have the following:

```
var feedbackString = "<p id='feedbackTxt'>" + currentQuizNode.find("Feedback").text() + "</p>";
$("#quizFeedback").append(feedbackString);
```

Thank you in advance,
Attila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var feedbackString = "<p id='feedbackTxt'>" + 
  currentQuizNode.find("Feedback").text().
    replace(/"(.*)"/, "<span style='font-style: italic;'>$1</span>").
    replace(/(\bat\b.*?\.)/, "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>$1</span>") + 
    "</p>";
$("#quizFeedback").append(feedbackString);
```

If you meant to say parenthesis instead of quotation marks then change:

```
replace(/"(.*)"/, "<span style='font-style: italic;'>$1</span>").
```

To:

```
replace(/(\(.*?\))/, "<span style='font-style: italic;'>$1</span>").
```

Answer (score 2):

```
currentQuizNode.find("Feedback").text().replace(/(.*\()(.*)(\).*patient is\s)(.*)/,"$1<span class=\"answer\">$2</span>$3<span class=\"risk\">$4</span>")
```

very ugly but it works :P